# How to resolve "An error occurred. Please try again." on YouTube Channel page

Tags: youtube

After I created another YouTube channel from my Gmail account I am getting the error shown in the image below. How can I solve it?

[image: An error occurred. Please try again.]

Comment: there isn't really *the* solution for this problem because "an error" is a catch-all phrase for a whole zoo of errors.